# Random forest tree figure is cut off in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to create a tree in R but some of the text from the bottom of the figure is being cut off. The text on nodes is also on nodes rather than below them, making it difficult to read. I'm using these commands:

```
tree<-rpart(X~A+B+C+D, method="anova", data=df1)
plot(tree, uniform=TRUE)
text(tree, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=1)
```

Changing the size of the figure window does not help the problem, nor does:

```
dev.off()
```

Decreasing the font size of text labels aids the cut off problem but makes the figure unreadable so is not much help. I'm very new to R so would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried printing it outside of R? To a png or other file? Check out `?png` or `?pdf`, those might help you out.

Comment: @Badger saving it as either still just shows the cut off figure

Comment: try using `libary(part.plot)`  and then `prp(tree)`. see if that improves anything